# Distributivity of certain infinite products

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, posets, infinite-combinatorics

Suppose we have a sequence of posets $\{\mathbb P_n : n\in\omega\}$ such that for each $n$, $\mathbb P_{n+1}$ is $|\mathbb P_n|^+$-distributive.  Is $\prod_{n>0} \mathbb P_n$ necessarily $|\mathbb P_0|$-distributive?

Comment: Is the product a full support one?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Jawohl.

Comment: And when you say $\kappa$-distributive, do you mean the intersection of $\kappa$ dense open sets is dense, or that for any $\alpha<\kappa$ the intersection of $\alpha$ dense open sets is dense?

Comment: The latter.  It’s the “right” definition since $\kappa$-closed implies $\kappa$-distributive.